# javaScript:passing argument to eventListener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

i'm try to make something and i made this piece of code,but when i press the botton it's happend for a sec and then disappear,am i donig passing the arguments wrong or something?
here the code is:

```
{
        var fil1;
        var rtextDiv;
        for (var i = 0; i < dmsg.getElementsByClassName('refilter').length; i++) {
            var refilterInput = dmsg.getElementsByClassName('refilter')[i];
            refilterInput.addEventListener('keyup', firstfilter(rtextDiv, fil1,refilterInput));
        }

    };

    function firstfilter(e, rtextDiv, fil1, refilterInput) {
        rtextDiv = refilterInput.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('rtext')[0];
        while (rtextDiv.firstChild) {
            rtextDiv.removeChild(rtextDiv.firstChild);
        }
        fil1 = filteredPropertiesTable(res, refilterInput.value);
        rtextDiv.appendChild(fil1);
    };
```

edited as the comment said:

```
{
        var fil1;
        var rtextDiv;
        for (var i = 0; i < dmsg.getElementsByClassName('refilter').length; i++) {
            var refilterInput = dmsg.getElementsByClassName('refilter')[i];
            refilterInput.addEventListener('keyup', function()
           {firstfilter(rtextDiv,fil1,refilterInput)(rtextDiv, fil1,refilterInput)});
         );
        }

    };

    function firstfilter(e, rtextDiv, fil1, refilterInput) {
        rtextDiv = refilterInput.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('rtext')[0];
        while (rtextDiv.firstChild) {
            rtextDiv.removeChild(rtextDiv.firstChild);
        }
        fil1 = filteredPropertiesTable(res, refilterInput.value);
        rtextDiv.appendChild(fil1);
    };
```

is it true know?can i pass argument that way?

Comment: Once you add the parenthesis, the function is called, not referenced, so you can't do it like that, you need an anonymous function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are actually executing the handler:

```
refilterInput.addEventListener('keyup', firstfilter(rtextDiv, fil1,refilterInput));
```

You should just present the handler name:

```
refilterInput.addEventListener('keyup', firstfilter);
```

And the handler can be improved:

```
function firstfilter(e) {
    var rtextDiv = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('rtext')[0];
    while (rtextDiv.firstChild) {
        rtextDiv.removeChild(rtextDiv.firstChild);
    }
    var fil1 = filteredPropertiesTable(res, this.value); // you didn't say what is res
    rtextDiv.appendChild(fil1);
};
```

Comment: tnx,another problem is the arguments,they are defined globally,am i access to them by this way?

Comment: i can't add the other stuffs in a reason of chaos,but here is the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alirh/xryj8awk/)